# undefined method `to_a' for "ens160":String

Tags: ruby

Ruby version - 2.0 gives this error

```
 # Convert values to a pair of bytes ...
 interface = values[0]
 values.collect! { |i| i.to_a.pack('H*') }
```

with the same code, we never faced this sort of issue in ruby 1.8.7

Comment: what's `values`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to ask that do to_a() does not work the same way in ruby 2.0 as it worked in ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: I am trying to connect puppet agent with master ..and i see a error .I understand it is due to ruby version mismatch..

Comment: error description...Error: Could not retrieve local facts: undefined method `to_a' for "ens160":String
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Could not retrieve local facts: undefined method `to_a' for "ens160":String

Comment: line.strip!
       next if line.match(/^[Ii]face.+/)
       next if line.match(/^(\r\n|\n|\s*)$|^$/)
       values = line.split("\t")[0..2]
       interface = values[0]
     values.collect! { |i| i.to_a.pack('H*') }
      sum = values[1].unpack('C4').inject { |i, j| i + j }
       unless sum > 0
       gateway = values[2].unpack('C4')
      gateway_interface = interface
    else
      next
    end

Comment: @kanchan that's unreadable

Comment: @kanchan don't post that much code in a comment, edit your question instead.

Answer (score 3):

As of Ruby 1.9.0, [`String#`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html)s are no longer [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html). You can't simply iterate over a `String` or convert it to an [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) – *what* would you iterate over? What would the elements of the `Array` be?

In different contexts, a `String` can be interpreted as

- a sequence of bytes,
- a sequence of octets,
- a sequence of codepoints,
- a sequence of characters,
- a sequence of lines,
- a sequence of words,
- a sequence of sentences,
- a sequence of paragraphs,
- a sequence of sections,
- a sequence of paragraphs,
- … and many other things.

You have to tell Ruby *what* interpretation you want. That's what the various iteration methods in the `String` class are for:

- [`String#each_byte`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-each_byte)
- [`String#each_char`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-each_char)
- [`String#each_codepoint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-each_codepoint)
- [`String#each_line`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-each_line)

There are also corresponding methods which represent the `String` as an `Array`:

- [`String#bytes`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-bytes)
- [`String#chars`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chars)
- [`String#codepoints`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-codepoints)
- [`String#lines`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-lines)

Note that all of those methods [already exist in Ruby 1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html) as well, and in fact, treating `String`s as `Enumerable`s was considered deprecated in Ruby 1.8.7.

It is unclear from your code what exactly you are trying to do, but my best guess is that you are looking for `String#chars`.

Comment: thenks a lott for  such a detailed explanation.I am completely new to ruby language so may be things are not vei clear to me as of now but let me send the code snippet again so that u can suggest also i understand from the link u sent that i need to replace to_a() with str.each_char.to_a()

Comment: No, you should replace it with `str.chars`, like I wrote in the last paragraph.

Comment: ok i am unable to send the code ..it is removing all newline characters

Comment: and did str.chars will work for server with ruby 1.8.7 ?

Comment: i think i need to upgrade all sever to 2.0 and replace to_a() with simple string.char or string.byte depending on requirement

Comment: Yes, like I *also* wrote in the penultimate paragraph, and you could trivially look up in the documentation yourself, [`String#chars`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-chars) also exists in Ruby 1.8.7. It works a little bit different, though, in that it returns an `Enumerator`, not an `Array`.

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7. has been unmaintained for 3 years, and there are numerous unpatched security holes.

Comment: hi, do i need to replace "  values.collect! { |i| i.to_a.pack('H*') }"...where value is a array with  "values.collect{ |i| i.char('H*')} "...please confirm

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Did you read the documentation I linked to?

Comment: hi,i tried to change the code with (values.collect! { |i| i.chars.to_a.pack('H*') }) but i get an error which says ( nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your exact question

> Why does `to_a()` not work the same way in ruby 2.0 as it worked in ruby 1.8.7?

It is because in ruby 1.8.7, strings were enumerables: https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html. Which means they included the Enumerable module, which had method `.to_a`.

This was already not the case in ruby 1.9.3 and up. That's why.

So either use ruby 1.8.7 everywhere or change that facts retrieval code (or whatever it is) to not use now-nonexistent `String#to_a`.

Comment: @kanchan: I have no idea what your requirements are. But you're welcome to peruse the documentation for String, which has all available methods and their descriptions and examples. Link to one for ruby 1.8.7 is in the answer. Here's one for ruby 2.0.0: [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html).